# How to convert array of date strings to date?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, date

Need to convert array of dates type from string to date.

Below is the input:

```
medicalData = [
  {
    name: 'Allergy',
    status: 'Normal',
    testDates: ['2023-07-02T13:21:29.643Z', '2023-07-03T13:21:29.644Z']
  },
  {
    name: 'Asthma',
    status: 'Deficient',
    testDates: ['2023-08-02T13:21:29.643Z', '2023-08-03T13:21:29.644Z']
  }
];
```

medical.service.ts:

```
const result = await this.medicalRecordRepository.create({
    medicalData: medicalData // need to know how to use new Date() here
});
```

medical.schema.ts:

```
class MedicalData {
  @Prop()
  name: string;

  @Prop()
  status: string;

  @Prop()
  testDates: [Date];
}

export class MedicalRecord extends Document {
  @Prop()
  medicalData: MedicalData[];
}
```

I need the testDates to be saved in database as array of dates not array of date strings.

Need some valuable help

Comment: When you say "as date", what do you mean?

Comment: in database, data type of dates in the testDates array should be saved as date

Comment: So turn them into Date instances with the Date constructor? What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried new Date() before saving, but the array structure is modified.

Comment: You could `.map()` the source arrays into arrays of Date objects.

Answer (score 1):

A feasible approach was to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the medical data twice

- the outer `map` for each medical data entry which uses [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variable_names_and_providing_default_values) and [rest property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) for the arguments as well as [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for creating a copy of the very data entry
- and a nested `map` which creates another variant of each data entry's `testDates` array where the latter's items are [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instances ...

```js
const medicalData = [{
  name: 'Allergy',
  status: 'Normal',
  testDates: ['2023-07-02T13:21:29.643Z', '2023-07-03T13:21:29.644Z'],
}, {
  name: 'Asthma',
  status: 'Deficient',
  testDates: ['2023-08-02T13:21:29.643Z', '2023-08-03T13:21:29.644Z'],
}];

/*
const result = await this.medicalRecordRepository.create({
  medicalData: medicalData.map(({ testDates, ...rest }) => ({
    ...rest,
    testDates: testDates.map(dateStr => new Date(dateStr))
  }))
});*/

console.log({
  medicalData: medicalData.map(({ testDates, ...rest }) => ({
    ...rest,
    testDates: testDates.map(dateStr => new Date(dateStr))
  }))
});
```

**Note:**

The SO specific logging of the above stack-snippet renders each `Date` instance as a stringified version of itself. A browser's console logging though would display a data-structure with date instances.